# Why is the Leviathan scared of the Kilbit?

Tags: maseches-shabbos, leviathan

Wikipedia's article about Leviathan makes the following claim:

> However, in spite of his supernatural strength, the leviathan is afraid of a small worm called "kilbit", which clings to the gills of large fish and kills them.

It's source is [Shabbos 77b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.77b.7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) which says:

> תנו רבנן, חמשה אימות הן אימת חלש על גבור: אימת מפגיע על הארי, אימת יתוש על הפיל, אימת סממית על העקרב, אימת סנונית על הנשר, **אימת כילבית על לויתן**.

This says nothing about what the Kilbit is or why the Leviathan is afraid of it. So why is the Leviathan afraid of the Kilbit? Is it as Wikipedia claims a small worm that clings to the gills of large fish and kills them? What is the source for this?

Comment: Rashi there calls it a small bug that goes in the ears of big fish, not sure if ear is ever used to mean gill?

Comment: It is a small non-kosher fish as per its mentioning in other parts of shas

Comment: It grows in the brine of tahor fish. Perhaps it is parasitic?

Comment: @YaacovDeane Where is it reported to be affected on its gills? What's the source for this?

Comment: @YaacovDeane About the Leviathan.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your quote from tractate Shabbat, each of the 5 types of *dread* pertain to something much smaller and weaker afflicting and even overpowering something much more powerful.

In the case of the Leviathan, (*a giant sea creature which according to many is an actual kosher fish with fins and scales that will ultimately be served at the Feast of the Moshiach during the days of the Moshiach*), it is reported to be affected on its gills.

In [Rashi's comment on the Kilbit to Shabbat 77b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.77b.7?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Shabbat.77b.7.4&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en), he says that it is a *sheretz* that enters the *ears* of the fish. In fish anatomy, it's [organ for hearing is behind the gill plate like is illustrated in this linked image](https://www.offthescaleangling.ie/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Weberian-ossicles-768x861.jpg).

At the end of Rashi's comment, there is a note pointing to [Rashbam to Bava Batra 77b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A9%22%D7%A1/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%90/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%94), who says:

> **באוסייה -** בנחיריו של דג נכנס השרץ ונראה לי דהיינו כילבית כדאמרי' בעלמא (שבת עז: ע"ש) שלשה אימות הן חלש על הגבור אימת כילבית על לויתן:

Rashbam clarifies that this Sheretz enters via the *nostrils* of the fish, meaning it's breathing passage, which in fish anatomy means via the gills.

The *Kilbit* therefore sounds like a marine parasite like [Neobenedenia](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29763664/) which is a type of [Monogenea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenea). They are hermaphroditic, reproduces rapidly infects the gills and can be fatal to its host.

This same parasite is also discussed in [Chullin 67b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.67b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) quoting Rav Sheshet ben Rav Idi, who calls this parasite Kukeyan. There is discussion there about how the parasite enters the fish which concludes, like Rashbam states, that it enters via the gills.

> והלכתא קוקיאני אסירי מ"ט מינם ניים ועיילי ליה באוסייה תולעים דרני דבשרא אסירי דכוורי שריין

The Maharsha to Chullin 67b also associates this Kukeyan with the Leviathan which he says is a ***dag tahor*** because it has scales and fins and will be served at the Feast of Moshiach as part of the meal.

So in context, perhaps the *dread* of the Leviathan is that since there is only one of it (*its mate was destroyed*), it could be made invalid via the Kukeyan and would not be permitted for use in Moshiach’s seudah.